# Functions such that $f(x)$ is ordered the same way as $x$

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory, monotone-functions

I am interested in functions $$
f:
\left|
  \begin{array}{rcl}
    \mathbb{R}^n & \longrightarrow &\mathbb{R}^n \\
    \mathbf{x} & \longmapsto &(f_1(\mathbf{x}),\ldots,f_n(\mathbf{x})), \\
  \end{array}
\right.$$ such that the ordering of the coefficients of $\mathbf{x}$ is the same as the one of $f(\mathbf{x})$ for all $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. such that, for any $i,j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$,
$$x_i \leq x_j \implies f_i(\mathbf{x}) \leq f_j(\mathbf{x}).$$

Is there a name for this?

This seems related to monotonicity. For instance, if $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ is an increasing function and $h: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^+$ a non-negative function, the function $$f: \mathbf{x} = (x_1,\ldots,x_n) \mapsto (h(\mathbf{x})g(x_1),...,h(\mathbf{x})g(x_n)),$$ will satisfy the condition above. Maybe it is just implied by some multivariate notion of monotonicity ?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean ${\bf x} =(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \longmapsto (f_1({\bf x}),\ldots,f_n({\bf x}))$? I ask because $x$ is generally used for scalars, so one would expect to see $x\in\bf R$ rather than $x\in{\bf R}^n$. Or maybe you mean $f : {\bf R} \longmapsto {\bf R}^n$?

Comment: Do you also require the converse (i.e., $f_i(x) \le f_j(x) \implies x_i \le x_j$)? Taking the contrapositive, one gets $f_i(x) > f_j(x) \implies x_i > x_j$, so it suffices to consider what happens if $f_i(x) = f_j(x)$. Perhaps, that should imply $x_i = x_j$.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum yes, my $x$s are vectors, but I'll update the question using boldfaces for vectors, it's indeed a bit clearer

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang That's a good point! I don't have precise requirements, but I think it would make sense to indeed add an equality condition. I would be interested in any notion or characterisation of this sort, regardless of what happens in the equality case.

Comment: The relation of "having the same component ordering" partitions $\Bbb R^n$ into finitely many regions, and your condition on $f$ is just that it maps each region into itself.

Comment: It's not monotonicity. Monotonicity relates different function values to each other ($x_1<x_2\implies f(x_1)<f(x_2)$) whereas this condition applies independently to individual function values ($x\sim f(x)$). See my previous comment. These functions are not generally monotonic with respect to any order on $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @Karl Thanks! Indeed, saying that it maps each region into itself is one nice way to characterize it. My question on the relationship to monotonicity was related to finding representations similar (and ideally more general/complex) to the one I used above, that uses univariate monotonic functions. I agree it's unlikely that the condition is equivalent to monotonicity with respect to a certain order.